# Hi, I am new to selenium and trying to put the text in status (box) on a site to post to one of my friend. However, I'm unable to do this

Tags: java, selenium

I am new to selenium and trying to put the text in status (box) on a site to post  to one of my friend. However, I'm unable to do this as text is not getting in while I'm able to highlight the same field. There is something wrong which I'm unable to find while searched a lot on google.

**Java Selenium code is here:**

```
package facebookmessaging;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


public class FacebookMessaging {

    private static WebDriver driver = null ;
    private static String decPassword = "HUMHUMMMMMM==";

    public static void main(String[] args) {




        String strPassword = EncodingAndDecodingClass.decodingMethod (decPassword);

         driver = new FirefoxDriver ();
         WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
         driver.navigate().to("https://www.facebook.com/");
         driver.manage().window().maximize();
         driver.findElement(By.name("email")).clear();
         driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("youremailid");
         driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).clear();
         driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).sendKeys(strPassword);
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[starts-with(@id,'u_0')]")).click();

        WebElement waitElement;
         waitElement= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[(@class='_1frb') and (@name='q')]")) );
         waitElement.clear();
         waitElement.sendKeys("YourFriendName");
         waitElement.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);

         waitElement= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[(@class='_52eh _5bcu') and (text()='YourFriendName')]")) ); 
         waitElement.click();

// code is working fine upto above line of code


// The below two lines of code is not working
WebElement element  = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='_1mf _1mj']/span");
waitElement.sendKeys("Hello ma'am");




//Method for highlighting an element on web page
/*  public static void fnHighlightMe(WebDriver driver,WebElement element) throws InterruptedException{
          //Creating JavaScriptExecuter Interface
           JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

              //Execute javascript
                 js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.border='4px groove green'", element);
    } */
```

**HTML for the textbox field is:**

```
<div class="notranslate _5rpu" contenteditable="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="js_i7" aria-multiline="true" data-testid="status-attachment-mentions-input" role="textbox" spellcheck="true" style="outline: medium none; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word;" aria-describedby="placeholder-1r5me">
<div data-contents="true">
<div class="" data-block="true" data-editor="1r5me" data-offset-key="4n5ih-0-0">
<div class="_1mf _1mj" data-offset-key="4n5ih-0-0">
<span data-offset-key="4n5ih-0-0">
<br data-text="true">
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: give only significant part of problem in subject

Comment: You are not allowed to scrape Facebook as per the [ToS](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms)

Comment: Give us  specfic code where  issue occured

Comment: // The below two lines of code is not working
WebElement element  = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='_1mf _1mj']/span");
waitElement.sendKeys("Hello ma'am");

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. According to the HTML it seems as if the input is not the span, but the div.

```
WebElement waitElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("///div[@data-testid='status-attachment-mentions-input']"); 
waitElement.sendKeys("Hello ma'am");
```

Comment: Hi JOberloh, Thanks for your input, yes its working now.

Comment: If so please accept the answer with the checkmark under the answer I submitted so others will be able to see the correct answer.